# Unable to add Blocked as a column to an Azure Dev Ops kanban board

Tags: azure-devops

We moved from on-premise TFS 2019, to Azure Dev Ops version Dev18.M170.6

This resurrected the `Blocked` state on a bug work item, and people have been setting the status.

What we didn't anticipate though, is those tickets disappearing from the kanban board, as the default columns are `New`, `Active`, `Resolved` and `Closed`.

When I try to customise the columns and add a new entry for `Blocked`, it's not an available state from the drop-down.

[image]

How do I get `Blocked` to appear in the drop-down, so I can add a column for it?

Answer (score 0):

Please enter **Organization Settings**--> **Boards**--> **Process**--> enter your process --> select the work item **Bug** -->**State** and then add a new state for it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see Organisation Settings, only Project or Collection settings.

Comment: click on the organization icon and then you find the setting under that view(left-buttom)

Comment: Can you update the answer with a screenshot of that, please? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: We can only get as far as ../DefaultCollection/_settings/process, we can't then edit the process.